# Trying to set up code when it reaches a certain number , the button becomes disable and can go no futher

Tags: javascript, html, numbers

**THIS IS MINE JAVASCRIPT**
I'm having trouble figuring out a way to disable the button feature. When it reaches a certain number.

```
let counter = document.getElementById("counter");
let add = document.querySelector(".add");
let minus = document.querySelector(".minus");

let count = 0;
>add.addEventListener("click", () => {
    >>count ++;
    >>>counter.innerHTML = count;

   >if (count > 10) {
    return;
    }
});

>minus.addEventListener("click" , () =>{
    >>count --;
    >>>counter.innerHTML = count;
});
```

Comment: you should test the condition (`if`) before changing the innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button with `add.setAttribute('disabled', 'true')`:

```js
let counter = document.getElementById("counter");
let add = document.querySelector(".add");
let minus = document.querySelector(".minus");

let count = 0;
add.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count++;
  counter.innerHTML = count;

  if (count >= 10) {
    add.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
  }
});

minus.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count--;
  counter.innerHTML = count;
});
```

```html
<p id="counter">0</p>

<button class="add">+</button>
<button class="minus">-</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show you how you can manage the disabling/enabling of the buttons according to count. I have created a single event listener that gets applied to both buttons and is able to determine if it's the plus or minus that was clicked. I moved the disabling stuff into it's own function since we need to call it on page load as well as in the button listeners. This also has the benefit of having a max and min set of values you can disable on. Plus, it's dynamic, so if you go up to 10 it will disable, but if you minus, it will re-enable, if that makes sense.

```js
let counter = document.getElementById("counter");
let mathButton = document.querySelectorAll(".math");

let count = 0;
let max = 10,
  min = 0
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  counter.innerHTML = count
  manageButtons()
  mathButton.forEach(m => {
    m.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let inc = e.target.classList.contains('minus') ? -1 : 1;
      mathButton.forEach(b => b.removeAttribute('disabled'));
      counter.innerHTML = count;
      manageButtons()
      count += inc;
    });
  });
});

function manageButtons() {
  if (count >= max) document.querySelector(".add").setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  if (count <= min) document.querySelector(".minus").setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

```html
<div id='counter'></div>
<button class='math add'>+</button> <button class='math minus'>-</button>
```

Comment: OOh I love this method! Thank you

Comment: Wonderful - if it helps solve your question, pls accept it as the answer. Cheers